# Need all known countries's state abbreviation

Tags: php, mysql, api, yii2, geolocation

I am working on a project, where i have to show countries & states both in drop down. I have all countries short name, get form

http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json.

But I don't have state` abbreviation of each country. 
I found some of country from wiki :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:US

Is that any repository or api so that i can update my table with state`s short name.

Comment: Nope. Because each country has its on names for states,countrs,citys. If you have an api that will deliver this information in all languages.... this api will be paid i thing. You have to crawl the web until you have all collected taht you need.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318203/get-2-letter-state-province-abbreviation  && https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html

Comment: Mainly i need state's abbreviation of all countries.

Comment: https://smartystreets.com/features   - google more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to free state code list from https://www.ip2location.com/free/iso3166-2

Comment: It seems most of the state are there what i was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you have mysql installed with default schemas. you will find what you need under the world schema.

Comment: looks more like a comment than an answer

Comment: I checked at mysql official website ,https://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/ . Are you talking about this .

Comment: @  RST, actually it's a comment. reputation level does not allow me to comment before placing an answer